# Amazon EC2 Windows IIS Cannot access port 80 remotely

Tags: amazon-ec2, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

For some reason no matter what I do I cannot access my IIS server remotely using port 80 like you would view a regular website. I am using Windows Server 2012 RC2.
Localhost shows IIS running locally but trying to access the server remotely using the IP or assigned amazonaws domain name doesn't resolve.

Here are screenshots of my settings.
[image: Windows Firewall]

[image: Inbound Rules]

[image: IIS Running]

[image: Server Settings]

Thanks for any help. I am a developer with little to no server setup experience and this is probably a stupid question so thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the Security Group for your EC2 instance allow inbound traffic to port 80? If not, then that's your problem.

Comment: This solved it didn't realize I had to do additional things withing the AWS console thank you. Please answer below and I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the Security Group for your EC2 instance allow inbound traffic to port 80? If not, then that's your problem. You'll need to modify the Security Group for that EC2 instance to allow inbound HTTP traffic.